# Why does JAVAC says, Package <pkg_name> does not exist?

Tags: java, database, compiler-errors

I'm writing a Java App, which uses H2Embedded Database, for this i downloaded the H2 Database source and placed it with my java file which contains the Main method of my program.

i.e., I've Placed the org folder of H2 database source within the same directory which has Test.java(Contains Main Method).

Now I'm using this import statement, in the Test.java :

```
import org.h2.jdbcx.*;
```

Now, when i try to compile Test.java, using :

> $ javac Test.java

It says :

> Test.java:1: error: package org.h2.jdbcx does not exist
>   import org.h2.jdbcx.*;

The directory Structure :

```
--> Test.java
--> org\  
      |
      ---> h2\
            |
            ---> jdbcx\
                    |
                    ---> *.java  (Files)
```

How can i Solve this? Its my First java App so kinda Confused.Thank you.

Comment: I would guess that whatever jar holds the package you're trying to import does not exist on your CLASSPATH.

Comment: Show a visual representation of your directory structure or describe it in more detail.   If for instance you have source code for a class named org.h2.jdbcx.blah it needs to reside in a directory named org/h2/jdbcx under where you Test.java resides.

Comment: The Files i'm importing are .java files, and they are present in the directory - org/h2/jdbcx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package that you are importing should contain `.class` files, not `.java` files.

Then run `javac -cp . Test.java`.

Or you can add the h2db.jar file to some directory (LIB_DIR_PATH) and run `javac -cp LIB_DIR_PATH/h2db.jar Test.java`.

You should also check the [Java PATH and CLASSPATH tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html).

Comment: By mistake, i posted "java", i'm using "javac". Thank you, i'll compile those packages first